# Select from table where one value is present and other values no

Tags: sql, database-design

I have 2 tables - Products and Invoices

The Invoice table has this structure

```
invoiceId 
productId 
invoiceType
```

The invoiceType has this values:

- proforma
- avans
- final

How can I select the products from Products Table that have only the 'proforma' value in InvoiceType column from Invoice table and not the other two (avans, final)?

Comment: just curiosity: what `avans` means?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from invoices i
              where i.productid = p.productid and i.invoicetype = 'proforma'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from invoices i
                  where i.productid = p.productid and i.invoicetype <> 'proforma'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from products p
where Exists 
     (Select * from Invoices
      Where productId = p.productId 
         and invoiceType = 'proforma')
   and Not Exists 
     (Select * from Invoices
      Where productId = p.productId 
         and invoiceType in ('avans', 'final'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql should look like the below, without knowing the exact field names this is the best I can do:

Select * from invoices 
Inner join products on products.productid=invoices.productid
Where invoices.invoicetype ='proforma'

Answer (score 0):

This should be 1 full scan of the database:

```
select *
from Products p
join (
      select i.productId
      from Invoice i
      group by i.productId
      having max(case when i.nvoiceType = 'proforma' then 1 else 2 end) = 1) iSum
on P.productId = iSum.productID
order by p.productId
```